# Unrelated "related questions" keep appearing because of high vote count

Tags: bug, related-questions

[image]

The second question in this screenshot, to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array), very commonly appears in the "related questions" sidebar of any Java question, even though it's not related.

Could the "related questions" algorithm maybe be changed to have a cap on the amount by which score can influence a question's relatedness?

Comment: Yeah, that's an outlier.  I imagine that you could simply discard vote results that are, say, more than three Standard Deviations away from the norm.

Comment: MSE: [Unrelated popular content constantly in related links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223880/unrelated-popular-content-constantly-in-related-links-i-e-score-contribution-s)

Comment: Java is definitely not as bad as JS and HTML when it comes to this issue...

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm that this definitely does not apply solely to Java. In fact, JavaScript questions seem to completely fail to provide a single related question in the related tab almost 100% of the time. To give an example:

[image: A lot of questions with obscene numbers of upvotes that have nothing to do with the topic]

And if you're wondering what the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978921/answer-does-not-get-shown-in-a-message-box) I was viewing was, the title is *Answer does not get shown in a message box*. Not one of the related questions has to do with message boxes, and the person writing the question almost certainly did not care about the color `chucknorris` or about JS prototyping.

I was unable to find anything about vote weighting on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected), only about the vocabulary/phrase searching. I'm expecting some sort of system which assigns each question a score for how well it matches, then uses an algorithm like averaging to combine that score with the number of upvotes.

Obviously, from the state of the related questions tab, that's not working. A better system might be to take the 20 or so best matching, then choose those with the highest upvotes and maybe some other factors. The number originally selected could be tweaked a little to ensure that enough questions get through without too much junk.

In case anyone wonders, "So what?", I think that a functioning "Related" menu/list could be very useful for a number of reasons:

- Finding questions which may help with more issues "down the road" when using a specific technique
- Presenting the user with more information about their question, potentially giving them more options or workarounds
- Giving useful background knowledge about a technique or issue which may help with debugging or implementation