# "Related" suggestions aren't related at all

Tags: discussion

More often than not I see "related" suggestions on questions that aren't related at all, except that they happen to be using the same language. At least, this tends to happen within the PHP section. For example:

Question: *[How to access a passed object's element in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352482/newbie-to-php-how-to-access-a-passed-objects-element)*

Related suggestions (color coded for how relevant they are):

[image: Related suggestions example]

The question is about how to access an object property and the suggestions are about SQL, user input, arrays, etc. Other than being highly upvoted questions and using PHP, they don't make any sense in relation to the question at all.

Can this somehow be improved? Maybe something like "If no related matches are found, change the title to 'Suggested Questions'" or something?

Comment: "passed objects element" is pretty well meaningless, and they do all at least have PHP in the titles. When the Related questions are a poor match, this could actually be evidence that the question is unclear. I don't know any PHP, but looking at the question it seems to be yet another disguised "please debug the code for me, without any of the missing context that actually causes the error" question.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Unrelated "related questions" keep appearing because of high vote count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266605/2821954)

Comment: Related (hopefully) on meta.SE: [Unrelated popular content constantly in related links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223880/756727) and [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/756727) (This second one maybe explains why it doesn't work so well..)

Comment: Yeah, I gave up editing the question trying to make the related section more relevant. I guess unlike some other language-prefixed tags, PHP rarely has them and instead uses generic tags that confused the algorithm.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Although I agree with most of what you said, obviously matching "PHP" on PHP related questions hardly makes any sense. You might as well select random questions in the category. Anyway, I understand it has to do with the user typing PHP within the title and from the related questions I found and linked here, it's pretty clear that the related filter is simply of pretty poor quality and has been like that for years. Hence my proposal to stop calling it "related" and maybe at least change that to "possibly related". At least it'll become less confusing.

Comment: For the example question, what is the gist of it? Did they use "element" instead of "property"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It seems to me that the related algorithm just picked up on the word "PHP" within the title, selected the most popular questions with "PHP" in it as well and pushed them forward. Later on a mod removed PHP from the title, but that had no effect on the related suggestions. That however could simply be a result of caching to reduce server load. They did use "element" instead of "property".

Comment: *Can this somehow be improved?* Almost certainly, will it be, probably not. I can't see SO Inc prioritising this.

Comment: @Liam Although there are some minor differences, I can agree that the question could be seen as a duplicate. That said, no, it doesn't answer the question. It just means the issue has been brought up before and no one bothers to actually do something about it. Anyway, I'll close it as a duplicate of that question, hoping that someone will actually pick it up this time. However, knowing SE, this is probably one of those things not important enough to ever do something about imho.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm basically picks the keywords of the title of the question, e.g. `PHP`, `element` in this case. Other words, e.g., `How`, `to` are obviously ignored by the system. However, when the system does this, it filters some highly-voted questions out.

However, of course this is not accurate, especially since the algorithm just picks up the keywords, therefore leading the misleading questions in the `Related` section.

I agree with the improvement of the algorithm, but I'm not sure how much they can improve it. Maybe the developers can try something like using multiple keywords and trying the combinations to filter instead? It's never perfect of course, and there's always a fairly large error percentage.

Related questions:

- [Unrelated "related questions" keep appearing because of high vote count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266605/2821954)
- [Unrelated popular content constantly in related links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223880/756727)
- [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/756727)

Comment: *but I'm not sure how much they can improve it* this would be a good machine learning algorithm application.

Answer (score -2):

I guess one way could be to simply let users vote if they are related or not. This could possibly also be a review queue.

Comment: I don't think this is viable, it would require way more manpower and time to achieve this, especially if **every question** requires multiple reviewers to check **Multiple** other related questions

Comment: You're picturing relatedness vote-arrows to one side of each question in the related sidebar?  That could work to at least give a correction mechanism, or a signal that heuristics could potentially even learn from.  And a way for actually useful related questions to be marked for future readers.  (And reject ones that are poor).  But we definitely shouldn't expect people to put a lot of effort into curating that for every question, so not a review queue.  Truly related other questions can get linked in comments, at which point they'll appear in the "linked questions" sidebar.