# How can I make the search bar stop flashing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

This is what the search bar on the main site looks like for me after the recent redesign:

[image: A picture of a search bar. It says "Powered by AI" and that flashes.]

This is really distracting to me. It keeps flashing until I click to acknowledge it. That stops it from flashing, until the next time I open SO. I've already dismissed it three times.

Can we have an option to permanently turn off the flashing notification? Alternatively, does anyone have a userscript to turn it off?

Comment: "_Can we have an option to permanently turn off the flashing notification_" Disable OverflowAI search from your preferences? :P

Comment: @Abdul You may joke, but that's exactly what I did when I first noticed this. Fun thing, you can't just turn it back on, you have to wait in the queue again to get access to the feature.

Comment: There is a reason why the blink html tag became obsolete, because it is really, really annoying.  What were they thinking?

Comment: Maybe that's what the AI does - changes the color for maximum annoyance. Then when the AI has concluded which color scheme that's the maximum annoyance and caused most people to opt of it, they launch that color scheme network-wide... There are many _great_ projects going on at SO right now.

Comment: @ErikA huh >:( that's not what I was told... either I was misled, or someone didn't understand [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426246/11107541).

Comment: Sadly, SO constantly makes the site more annoying for users without any option to customize it

Comment: @starball I'm not sure that applies, I opted in via the settings menu as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426432/overflowai-search-is-now-available-for-alpha-testing-september-13-2023), not via the form linked on that question.

Comment: More <blink> please.

Comment: Hello, the animation is intended to only appear until you've interacted with or performed a search once. After that, the pulse should not re-appear again so this appears to be a bug that I went ahead and ticketed for investigation. Apologies for the inconvenience. Will report back when it's been addressed.

Comment: @tanj92 Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I was able to reproduce it on my end since I had interacted with the search bar a few times yesterday and it re-appeared when I visited the homepage this morning. By chance, were you on a MacOS machine when this occurred?

Comment: @tanj92 Yes, MacOS 13.5.1, using Firefox 118.0.2.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks! That could be the common denominator but won't know until we investigate some more.

Comment: I see it's opt-in so don't think it's a bug. If you don't want to see that just don't opt-in to that new search.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry A bug in an opt-in feature is still a bug, isn't it?

Comment: It is absolutely baffling that someone came up with the idea of pulsing the search bar, and it also got approved.

Comment: Eh, i think it's a perfectly acceptable design feature, *as long as it stops blinking and never starts again once you've interacted with it the first time or reloaded the page* which is the bug.

Comment: @NickODell we've made a change this morning. Can you let me know if you're still seeing the animation re-appear later today?

Comment: @tanj92 I'll turn my userscript off and let you know.

Comment: Sounds good, if anyone else is also having issues with this re-appearing after deploying this change, please ping me. Thanks!

Comment: I logged on this morning and did not see the animation re-appear so I'll be updating the tag to status-completed for now. Let me know if it re-appears for you, thank you!

Comment: @tanj92 Sounds good - I haven't seen it in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't opted in to enable OverflowAI search, but I do see some inline CSS with classes like `js-search-pulsing`, etc. that seem to do this.

This seems to (at least currently) be the only style tag in the head tag. So you could create a userscript that runs `document.querySelectorAll("head style")[0].remove()` to remove that CSS and hence remove the flashing.

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I turned your suggestion into a userscript. https://gist.github.com/nickodell/b56ddb22ba3fa7a1462271abdbdaab15 I'm going to leave this question open, since it sounds like this is a bug.

Comment: @NickODell You can shorten the code to just `document.querySelector('head style')?.remove()`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the rule I'm using:

```css
.js-input-border-pulsing, .js-search-pulsing, .js-text-pulsing {
  animation: none !important;
}
```

These classes are taken from this stylesheet, which should be somewhere in your `<head>`:

```html
<style type="text/css">.js-alpha-search-label { color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); }.js-search-pulsing { border-radius: 8px; border: 2px solid transparent; -webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite; animation: pulse 2s infinite; outline: 0 }@-webkit-keyframes pulse { from { border-color: transparent; } 50% { border-color: hsl(206, 93%, 83.5%); } to { border-color: transparent }}@keyframes pulse { from { border-color: transparent; } 50% { border-color: hsl(206, 93%, 83.5%); } to { border-color: transparent }}.js-input-border-pulsing { animation: blink 2s infinite; outline: 0; -webkit-animation: blink 2s infinite; outline: 0 }@-webkit-keyframes blink { from { border-color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); } 50% { border-color: hsl(206, 93%, 83.5%); } to { border-color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); }}@keyframes blink { from { border-color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); } 50% { border-color: hsl(206, 93%, 83.5%); } to { border-color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); }}.js-text-pulsing { color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); animation: color-change 2s infinite; -webkit-animation: color-change 2s infinite; }@-webkit-keyframes color-change { from { color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); } 50% { color: hsl(206, 100%, 52%); } to { color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); }}@keyframes color-change { from { color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); } 50% { color: hsl(206, 100%, 52%); } to { color: hsl(210, 8%, 75%); }}</style>
```

Apply this rule with an extension of your choice. For me, a Chrome user, it's [Stylus](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne).