# AI search: sometimes returning no results, toggling off takes hours, opting back in days instead of instant

Tags: bug, search, overflow-ai, alpha, overflow-ai-search

I've opted into the AI search alpha. It has at least two serious bugs for me:

1. It doesn't seem to work for some search terms, e.g. when I [search for `colima`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=colima) it returns *nothing* even though there surely *are* questions mentioning that word:

   [image]

   It's fine if there is no summary available, just show me some relevant questions. This empty result is really confusing.
   This is what I get when I search in incognito window, logged out, 230 results:

   [image]
2. Even when I toggle off the "Enable OverflowAI Search" opt-in, I still get that "Powered by AI" buggy search. It doesn't seem to respect my opting out. (The [announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426432/overflowai-search-is-now-available-for-alpha-testing-september-13-2023/426449#426449) suggests one can opt out):

   [image]

   Update (2 hours later): By now the off-toggle seems to have propagated and be respected. So bug 2 (ignoring opt-out) appears to be smaller: a delay until it works rather than not working at all. [Or maybe that bug has been fixed or I have been manually opted out by someone]. I toggled back on for further testing and now there's a badge saying "Pending":

   [image]
3. It would be good if the opt-in/out toggle worked instantly. I might want to try it out again in a week for a bit, but I'm not keen to wait for more than 24h after I opt back in to see the changes manifest (it still says pending 24h after I toggled it back on).

Comment: Interesting, I opted out when the search bar started blinking, and that took immediate effect.

Comment: Re "*broken*" in the Title, some software or feature in 'alpha-testing' phase cannot be "*broken*", I would think, you probably mean *flawed* or *buggy*... Stg "*broken*" means that it used to work (correctly) in some previous state/version. // And yep indeed, I also find the 'Opt-in'/'Opt-out' workflow rather *strange*, it looks like a Toggle the User can control at will, but once you've opted out, you'll have to wait for several weeks (again) if you want to toggle it on again...

Comment: Also shoutout to it giving answers in a different language than was asked for lmao  https://i.imgur.com/MbtPbK3.png

Comment: Opt-in not being instant is by design, once you've opted out, opting in puts you back into the pending queue. I've been pending since they began testing this.

Comment: @KevinB My expectation would be that toggling wouldn't remove you from the list of Alpha testers, just turn off that feature for the moment, like toggling off a feature flag.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer i mean, there's a lot of things implemented in ways that I wouldn't expect/want them to be. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ for example, why can't I test this feature, having been a member of SO for 13 years *and* being a user who contributed to the data this thing is (ab)using?

Comment: "_It would be good if the opt-in/out toggle worked instantly_" I am once again linking to me asking about this and getting a wrong answer from staff: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426246/11107541

Answer (score 19):

Advanced search operators disable AI search, so as a workaround you can search for the following:

```
created:2000.. colima
```

The site was created in 2008 so this doesn't filter out any posts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I trust that this works but I couldn't verify as by now I seem to have succesfully been opted out.