# How hard would it be to implement auto-complete for tags when *searching*?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search-box

When entering a question, tags to add are auto-completed/suggested for completion.

However when I search using tags (i.e. enter "[something") tags *are not auto-completed/suggested*.

I think that would be a rather useful feature, so I wonder:

Is it too hard to implement, or did just nobody think of it yet?

Comment: Or it wasn't deemed *that* useful?

Comment: Well, if you mistype a single letter in a tag, then you get nothing...

Comment: For most other sites? Trivial. For Stack? Hard, uninteresting, and it doesn't yield enough money. At least unless you happen to have a few billion in venture capital lying around to throw at an unprofitable platform, then it might become very easy (or even harder if they treat it as AI pocket money instead)

Comment: Frequently I found myself following this workflow: Trying to search a specific topic, I wasn't sure which tags do exist, so I clicked the tags where I could search for them. Then I returned to the search, entering one of the tags I found. I just imagine this is not the way it should be.

Comment: Is it nescessary to ask the question like that, indirectly implying that SO is unable to implement this feature?

Comment: OK, what is "meta" really about, please?

Comment: I would love this feature: during going through questions for retagging I frequently construct queries like `[tag] -[othertag] -[othertag2]` and it will be easier with suggestions.

Comment: I don't really understand why you have to go there either, you can see that for yourself by reading existing questions and answers. You should be wondering how you make a good feature request instead I would say. To be honest I don't think they're even worth it anymore besides discussing about what could have been, the company really has its own roadmap nowadays and only asks for our input after the fact as a nicety. I do believe the site search feature is already on a roadmap to be revamped.

Comment: Rrgarding workflow you described though, if you are on tags page, you can simply click on needed tag, and it will lead you the the page with search over that tag.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can someone edit it to make it more clear what OP is saying/suggesting?

Comment: @TylerH would "auto-complete" make it make sense, in place of "complete"? seems fairly clear to me,

Comment: @KevinB Oh, yes autocomplete would make more sense.

Comment: I would actually reject the notion that this would be "that" hard to implement, given that it already exists for the tag box. If the exact same querying was used when a user types an opening tag character `[` in search, we'd have the feature. Obviously it's probably more nuanced than that, but I can't imagine it'd be _that_ much harder in the grand scheme... It's probably even user-scriptable, precisely because it already exists for the tag box.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I feel the salt in your answer, admitting that I'm not a JavaScript programmer. Still I wonder how much harder it is to start completion after a `[` rather than at the start of the input, given there is a working completion routine already.

Comment: Yes but as long as you keep approaching this from a perspective of how hard it is, you don't talk about things which actually matter. It shouldn't matter how hard or easy something is. It's a red herring and not for us to decide. The real question is: why isn't it there already? That is more likely a combination of reasons that have little to do with complexity and more to do with priority.

Answer (score 5):

The current search doesn't have any live-search or autocomplete functionality. I suppose if there was any interest in that existing they'd put some effort into having it autocomplete tags too, but at this point we're just waiting to see what becomes of [the upcoming semantic search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425766/preview-of-search-and-question-asking-powered-by-genai) that will replace what we currently have.

Comment: It will not replace what we currently have! But anyway, doesn't seem there's time for developing "auto-complete" when they are working on that feature.

Comment: What do you mean? it's literally a different search engine that opens the results in a dialog rather than going to a results page. It couldn't be more different from what we have.

Comment: It is different. I read that the option to use the existing search will be still available. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425766/preview-of-search-and-question-asking-powered-by-genai#comment968112_425780 Also see Tyler's comment under the same thread.

Comment: p.s. I should not be doing this. I am not good at nitpicking. Where's Cody when you need him? ;)

Comment: All good, ;) If you mean the new search will still support things like deleted:, created:, [tag], etc, my understanding is [that's going to be a feature of the new search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425766/preview-of-search-and-question-asking-powered-by-genai#comment968112_425780), not just a toggle back to the old one